# Glass is not see through in EEVEE

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass

I have these settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then I get this:

[image]

To get rid of the gray parts, I recalculated normals for the cup but the result is the same.

So I tried:

[image]

The result is:
[image]

I know the color is transparent, but it's not see through in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the roughness and IOR down. Eevee is a bit intense with distorting the IOR. Keep opaque settings.

To remove the grey edges turn the 'Edge Fading' to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any artifacts (if that's what's bothering you), disable the *Show Backface* option. You won't see any thickness though, for glass in Eevee does have limitations:

[image]